# Restoring a Document Library's content from a backup?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, backup, restore, content-database

I have a sharepoint **server** backup  and a database backup of the SQL2008 server which holds the sharepoint database.

Some infopath forms were deleted from the document library and I would like to know as to how I will be able to restore this document library's infopath forms, from any one of these backups??

Please advise.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? 2010?

Comment: Its Sharepoint Enterprise 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint 2010, this is a textbook case for an unattached content database restore. Long story short, you need to do the following steps:

1. Restore the database backup into your SQL 2008 instance
2. Add the database as an unattached content database via a Granular Restore in the Central Admin site.
3. Export the document library from the unattached content database
4. Import the document library back into your site collection.

For more details on unattached content databases in SharePoint 2010, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269602.aspx

If you're using SharePoint 2007, you won't be able to take this approach. You're going to have to restore the database backup and either remove the original content database from your current farm or attach the restored backup to a completely separate farm, then export the document library. You cannot attach two instances of the same content database to a SharePoint 2007 farm.

John

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a maintenance plan that backs up the sharepoint database, but do have a sql2008 server backup. I am not much of a database guy and am trying to figure out as to how I will be able to narrow down to the file location in the database. WE have abnout 4 instances running on our production sql2008 box.

Comment: I tlook slike we have a .mdf file. Will I be able to use this by inserting it into the the DATA directory of my SQL instance??

Answer (score 1):

There is a Step By Step instruction of how to do a granular restore from an SQL backup of the content database at [SharePoint 2010 Unattached Content Database Recovery: Not Recovery, Just Export](http://blog.sharepoint-recovery.com/2010/06/25/sharepoint-2010-unattached-content-database-recovery-not-recovery-just-export/)

Comment: http://intranet.company.com/site1/infopathForms/.... is where all the infopath forms are stored when I open it up in windows explorer. How does this help me figure out where in the database it gets stored? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is rather old but I just had the same problem and thoug my post might help others.
In my case I just needed to extract some documents from a library of an old SQL backup. I found a Codeplex solution called SharePoint 2010 File Recovery and it can be found here:
https://sp2010filerecovery.codeplex.com/